# Events of a maximum function

Tags: probability

I'm trying to state the different events that cause X in a set S to be the maximum value. so I'm not looking into the event that X is more than all the elements of S, but rather the events of X>Y>Z and X>Z>Y if we assumed that X,Y and Z belong to S.

Any book or reference that describes those disjoint events, I would appreciate your help

Comment: Uncertain.  Are you talking about [Order Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)?

Comment: no I'm not considering order statistics .. I'm trying to say that there are disjoint probabilities that cause x to be the maximum .. which are X>Z>Y and X>Y>Z ... I'm trying to generalize it for n number of elements in S. So that the total probability of X is maximum is pr(X-Y)*pr(Y-Z)+pr(X-Z)*pr(Z-Y)

Comment: So you are just considering those permutations as partition? Fixing $X$ being the maximum, you have the remaining $(n-1)$ elements which produce $(n-1)!$ permutations as your desired partition and you want to list them out? or?

Comment: I just wanted a refernce that describe the events and the arrangments that lead to the event that X is the maximum in the set. I used the definition of order statistic set so I hope it will work